# Nexus 4 - suddenly lost access to all Google sites

Tags: wi-fi, nexus-4, 4.3-jelly-bean

Nexus 4, stock 4.3, rooted. WiFi only for data, strong signal

Suddenly today, for no apparent reason, every app requiring access to a Google site stopped working:
Google Now gives "Network error"
Google Chrome gives "This webpage is not available" for any Google url, but works fine for any other url
Android Weather sits on "Updating"
Finance gives "Error. Network connection unavailable"
Google Maps gives blank screen
Play Store gives "Server Error"

The one exception to this is that Firefox can access any Google url, no problem. All other apps accessing the internet work fine.

I have tried rebooting - no effect.

Anyone have any ideas how to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: I suspect that it's indeed some localized Google issue. Is it still happening?

Answer (score 0):

Is it only Google services or all HTTPS sites? In any case, make sure the clock, date, and time zone is set correctly on the device.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a problem with your host file, located in "/etc/hosts".
To fix this you need root rights, then edit the host file and delete the line which says "android.clients.google.com"

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem, too. Found a good answer, finally, here:
http://www.galaxys4forums.net/forum/12-galaxy-s4-help/3671-problems-after-4-3-update-2.html
It's a matter of settings for the WiFi network you are connecting to.

Comment: Can you add some details to your answer? When that link no longer functions there's nothing useful here at all.